# Error 'duplicate definition' when compiling two C files that reference one header file

Tags: c, header, definition

I have two C files and one header that are as follows:

Header file header.h:

```
char c = 0;
```

file1.c:

```
#include "header.h"
```

file2.c:

```
#include "header.h"
```

I was warned about 'duplicate definition' when compiling. I understand the cause as the variable c is defined twice in both file1.c and file2.c; however, I do need to reference the header.h in both c files. How should I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 16):

First, don't define variables in headers.  Use the `extern` qualifier when declaring the variable in the header file, and define it in one (not both) of your C files or in its own new file if you prefer.

header:

```
extern char c;
```

implementation:

```
#include <header.h>
char c = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can leave the definition in the header but add `static`.  Using `static` will cause different program behaviour than using `extern` as in the example above - so be careful.  If you make it `static`, each file that includes the header will get its own copy of `c`.  If you use `extern`, they'll share one copy.

Second, use a guard against double inclusion:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

... header file contents ...

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `extern char c` in your header, and `char c = 0` in one of your `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

What is `char c` used for? You probably want it to be `extern char c` or if you want for this to be a separate variable for each compilation unit(source file) then you should use `static char c`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the header, then as a hack, in one (but not both) of your source files, you could do this:

```
#define c d
#include "header.h"
```

This will result in `char c = 0;` becoming `char d = 0;`, but of course, anywhere else that `c` is used, it will also become `d`, so it may not work at all.

Comment: +1 b/c it's insane, but a surprisingly useful hack for debugging embedded code with a bazillion 3rd party libraries!